# gdb memory addresses not matching memory address printed out by program

Tags: c, gdb

I have a basic C program like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int cookie;
    char buf[80];

    printf("A: %x B: %x\n", &buf, &cookie);
    gets(buf);

    if (cookie == 0x11111111){
        printf("You win!\n");
    } else {
        printf("THIS Didn't WORK");
    }
}
```

When I run it, the print statement prints `A: efbffab0 B: efbffb08`

Yet, if I were to open up this program in gdb and explore the memory address of any of the variables, I get a longer value then what the C program prints out:

```
Thread 2 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at challenge.c:10
10      if (cookie == 0x41424344){
(gdb) x/50x &buf
0x7ffeefbffab0: 0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344
0x7ffeefbffac0: 0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344
0x7ffeefbffad0: 0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344
0x7ffeefbffae0: 0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344
0x7ffeefbffaf0: 0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344  0x41424344
0x7ffeefbffb00: 0x41424344  0x00007f00  0x00011025  0x00000000
0x7ffeefbffb10: 0xefbffb28  0x00007ffe  0x20545f3d  0x00007fff
0x7ffeefbffb20: 0x20545f3d  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7ffeefbffb30: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0xefbffcb0  0x00007ffe
0x7ffeefbffb40: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xefbffd09  0x00007ffe
0x7ffeefbffb50: 0xefbffd4b  0x00007ffe  0xefbffd65  0x00007ffe
0x7ffeefbffb60: 0xefbffd74  0x00007ffe  0xefbffd85  0x00007ffe
0x7ffeefbffb70: 0xefbffdce  0x00007ffe
```

How come the address from my C program, `0xefbffab0` doesn't match the address gdb gives me, `0x7ffeefbffab0`?
Where does the `0x7ffe` prefix come from?

Comment: This is why you should *always* compile with `-Wall -Werror`. If people did this, it would avoid 50% of C questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: That should be in the [mre] instructions.

Comment: @Tyler: hopefully you were motivated to compile with `-Wall -Werror` (or equivalent for your compiler).  You should have seen something like this: `warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[80]'`  You should always compile with `-Wall`.  You should also refer to the [printf documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: This is an intentionally vulnerable piece of c code to practice buffer overflows that I didn't write. The question isn't what is wrong with the C code but how come the addresses differ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier for printing a pointer. The `x` specifier is for `unsigned int`, which on your system is 32 bits, and thus prints only part of the address (however this is just a coincidence, using the wrong format specifier is undefined behavior). The one you want is `p`, which is for `void *`:

```c
printf("A: %p B: %p\n", &buf, &cookie);
```

Comment: @Tyler Note that the `&buf` etc. may change when running under GDB and from run to run if ASLR is in effect.

Comment: @EmployedRussian shouldn't change when running under GDB as it should implicitly disable ASLR for the tracee through `personality(2)`

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't change under GDB (unless `set disable-randomization on`). But it can change outside GDB vs. under GDB.

Comment: Ahh I see, so %x is for printing unsigned ints. So when I try to print the 64-bit memory address as a 32-bit unsigned bit, I only get the first 8 digits.
Confirmed that using %p prints out the full 12 digits as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401128/why-there-are-two-different-lengths-for-addresses-in-32-and-64-bit)