# Migrating code to C#/Win32 causes exceptions

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, user32

In our (WinUI3-based) project, we've been using the P/Invoke packages to call low-level methods that modify the windows. But recently [all these packages have been deprecated](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/PInvoke) in favor of the source-generated [C#/win32 package](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).

However, I'm having some difficulties migrating all of our code to this new library.
The biggest issue I'm having is with the win32 sub-classing. In our current code we have this working like this (written by a collegue that left the company a year ago):

```cs
private delegate IntPtr WinProc(IntPtr hWnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowMessage Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private IntPtr _oldWndProc = IntPtr.Zero;

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, WinProc newProc);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, WinProc newProc);

// This static method is required because Win32 does not support GetWindowLongPtr directly
private static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, WinProc newProc)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, newProc);
    else
        return SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, newProc);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowMessage Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void SubClassingWin32()
{
    _hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

    var newWndProc = new WinProc(NewWindowProc);
    _oldWndProc = SetWindowLongPtr(_hwnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_WNDPROC, newWndProc);
}

private IntPtr NewWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, PInvoke.User32.WindowMessage Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
        [...]
    }
    return CallWindowProc(_oldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I tried to rewrite that to C#/Win32, but I get Execution Engine Exceptions.

```cs
private delegate LRESULT WNDPROCDelegate(HWND hWnd, uint Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// This static method is required because Win32 does not support GetWindowLongPtr directly
private static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(HWND hWnd, WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong) =>
#if x64
    PInvoke.SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
#else
    PInvoke.SetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32());
#endif

private void SubClassingWin32()
{
    _hwnd = (HWND)WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

    WNDPROCDelegate del = NewWindowProc;
    var newWndProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del);
    var oldWndProc = SetWindowLongPtr(_hwnd, WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_WNDPROC, newWndProc);
    _oldWndProc = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<WNDPROC>(oldWndProc);
}

private LRESULT NewWindowProc(HWND hWnd, uint Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
        [...]
    }
    return PInvoke.CallWindowProc(_oldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The original code seems to use a trick were the 3rd parameter of `SetWindowLongPtr` is passes a delegate that is implicitly converted into a function pointer. With C#/Win32 this doesn't seem possible, so I'm using `Marshal`.
The debugger shows `NewWindowProc` is being hit, so the first step seems to work, so I suspect something is going wrong in the line

```cs
_oldWndProc = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<WNDPROC>(oldWndProc);
```

or

```cs
PInvoke.CallWindowProc(_oldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
```

But it's hard to debug (any tips there would also be welcome.)

Has anybody done this? Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are these your own windows or are you changing windows of other processes?

Comment: Using delegates is a nice way to do it, why don't you just rip the code you need back from https://github.com/dotnet/pinvoke/tree/main/src/User32 ? Or get it from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72829193/403671

Comment: @PMF ours: this code is in a class `DesktopWindow` that is derived from `Window`. So that's why we're calling `GetWindowHandle(this);`

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the equivalent code for WPF, but not for WinUi.

Comment: Do you understand the differences between a 32 bit address and a 64 bit address with an Intel architecture?  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401128/why-there-are-two-different-lengths-for-addresses-in-32-and-64-bit

Comment: @SimonMourier we're trying to eliminatie "magic" code out of code base. This is a new application, we just released 1.0, and want to support it for 10 years. Having code in there that nobody can maintain is a risk. Thanks for the link. I noticed the link in the SO answer already is deleted, so maybe this already is a dated example and there are newer ways to do this in winui3.

Comment: @jdweng yes I do. C#/Win32 will handle most stuff, generating the correct functions and types. It's also generating the unicode "...W" versions by default, which is what we want

Comment: I understand you want to eliminate the deprecated nuget, but you won't eliminate the needed interop code as WinUI3 doesn't yet provide everything one may need to write a complete win32 desktop app with all what win32 has provided during 30 years. I'm just suggesting you rip that code piece the way you want, don't reinvent it. Just get rid of nuget dependency and copy the c# code back in yours, you don't *need* C#/win32 which carries some cumbernesses on its edges

Comment: @SimonMourier i understand that we wel need interop. And as my replacement code shows, I'm still using it. However it would be much nicer to have clean C# code without hacky dll imports (changing that 3rd parameter is not according to the user32 docs): it might even break with a new version and we'll be in world of hurt then. I would like to do it propely using something like the marshaller (C#9 function pointers aren't possible because the replacement method is not static).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well poop. The answer was looking me right into the eye.

I had already modified the original code, think I was smart and seeing the private field `_newWndProc` wasn't used anywhere. So I had made it a local variable.

and what happens then? You take a function pointer to a **local** delegate object, that is marked for finalization as soon as the scope ends... nothing is prolonging it's lifetime. I.e. the interop will use a pointer to an invalid object once it has been finilized!

So the solution is to undo my smart-ass optimization and make `newWndProc` a field again. (This has cost me some hours to debug!)

Comment: Could you please flag this for highlight?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Could you expand on your question?